# onLocationChanged returns old location

Tags: android, gps, location

In my application which tracks traveled distance i have two buttons. First one start's location updates, second stops them.

```
public void start(View view){
    cords = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        return;
    }

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
}

public void stop(View view) {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
}
```

Then i declare onLocationChanged where i calculate distance that user have traveled.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    cords.add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

    if (cords.size() > 1) {
        Location previousLocation = new Location("");
        previousLocation.setLatitude(cords.get(cords.size() - 2).latitude);
        previousLocation.setLongitude(cords.get(cords.size() - 2).longitude);

        stats.updateDistance(location.distanceTo(previousLocation));
    }
}
```

The problem is that when i stop measurements and then start them again, location returns old value. How could i get rid of this old value and start distance measurement from brand new location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that i didnt get old location but instead i got location measured by network not gps, that's why it was so inaccurate. When i was moving further away from buildings, gps started to work and location was correct. So to get rid of network measurement i check if location hasAltitude(), if it doesn't it means that it was measured by network so i can ignore it.

```
 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(location.hasAltitude()) {
        cords.add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

        if (cords.size() > 1) {
            Location previousLocation = new Location("");
            previousLocation.setLatitude(cords.get(cords.size() - 2).latitude);
            previousLocation.setLongitude(cords.get(cords.size() - 2).longitude);

            stats.updateDistance(location.distanceTo(previousLocation));
    }
```